# Grouping based on specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I struggling to build a data as per requirement but having some issues.

I want to display values in groupId column as per showing in my below image.

currently 3 groups in my data set in Red, Green and Blue , these groups were formed I actually in column TRXCODE 8202 contains 10% value of TRAMT which I have done already.

For example as per image -

- Column TRAMT on Row 2 is 10% of row 3 of TRAMT column
- Column TRAMT on Row 5 is 10% of row 4 of TRAMT column
- Column TRAMT on Row 7 is 10% of row 6 of TRAMT column

So I want information in groupId as per my image.

[image]

This is script of record set

```
CREATE TABLE #TempRecords 
(CODE VARCHAR(20), TRDATE DATE, TRBATCH INT, TRREF VARCHAR(20), TRXCODE INT, TRAMT decimal(8,2)
);

GO

INSERT INTO #TempRecords
 VALUES ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 1753, 31.20),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8202, 3.12),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8104, 589.68),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, -31.20),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, -589.68),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, -3.12),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, 554.60),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, 32.18),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, 3.22),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-09-25', 8737, '0000060259', 1701, 1104.00)

GO

SELECT * FROM #TempRecords
```

---

Recordset what I produced and showing in my image is based on following code

```
  SELECT *,DENSE_RANK () OVER(ORDER BY TRAMT1) as groupId
      FROM(
           SELECT CODE,
                  TRDATE,
                  TRBATCH,
                  TRREF,
                  TRXCODE,
                  TRAMT,
                  CAST(IIF(TRXCODE = 8202, TRAMT, TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))  AS TRAMT1
             FROM #TempRecords 
          ) AS SubRecSet
```

Thanks,

Comment: There are two "groupID" columns, last three rows of one having 8, 8, 8 and of the other having 8, 9, 10.  But the last three rows have all their other columns with the same information -- there is nothing to distinguish them from one another.  Is there a typo in one of the groupID columns?  There seems to be nothing for DENSE_RANK to go on...  Is the task to color code certain rows? With only those 3 colors? or with some other colors?  Or is the task to somehow change the groupID values?

Comment: Hi donPablo, Actually the color rows (Red, Green, Blue) are valid groups as I wanted to group only these rows where the value is 10% and other row based this 10% value is . As per my image row 2 is 10% of row 3 so I have to group these 2 rows the same case is with (groupid 3,3 & 4,4) rest all rows I don't want to group - hope this helps to understand the requirement

Comment: So the basic question is -- Does a given TRAMT1 contain any TRXCODE = 8202.  If so, colorize it, if not then no color.  Do you want to show only groups 2, 3, 4 and eliminate the other groups from the report?

Comment: TRXCODE 8202 contains 10% value in  TRAMT column of a other row - So I have to group 8202 row and that row where this 10% value is based on - So in this case groupid (2,2 - 3,3 & 4,4) are valid groups - I marked these row so I can group these rows. The I also want to display other rows but rest all other rows so I have to assign a unique number to each row - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what also works

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
    ,t2.Grouped
    ,DENSE_RANK () OVER(ORDER BY TRAMT1 + case when Grouped = 'G' then 0 else rn * .00001 end) as groupId

    FROM
    (Select *, Row_Number() Over (order by  TRAMT1 ) as rn From
        (Select *   , CAST(case when TRXCODE = 8202 then TRAMT else TRAMT * 0.10 end  AS DECIMAL(8,2))  AS TRAMT1
        From #TempRecords) as t0 
    ) as  t1

LEFT JOIN
    (Select distinct
        CAST(case when TRXCODE = 8202 then TRAMT else TRAMT * 0.10 end  AS DECIMAL(8,2))  AS TRAMT2
        ,case when TRXCODE = 8202 then 'G' else 'n' end as Grouped
        FROM #TempRecords  where case when TRXCODE = 8202 then 'G' else 'n' end = 'G'
    ) as t2
    on t1.TRAMT1 = t2.tramt2

    order by t1.tramt1
```

Comment: Hi donPablo, Your solution worked but can you please generate same result set without combining my query ? -  One more thing in create table you can add a *TransactionId* column with unique  values from 1-13 (Total 13 rows) as I forgot in my initial post.   Please don't combine my query in your result set and create a new query-  Appreciate your help. Looking forward for your next solution. Thanks

Comment: "without combining"/"don't combine" --> I don't understand that direction.  Also, any TransactionID  would just be some random numbers from 1-13 and not relate to the sequence of the resulting data.

Comment: Hi donPablo,  combining mean don't use my query what I pasted in this post- Just try to generate record set using my insert table statement. And you can add a additional column Transaction and assign a unique number to each row.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do those parts during your Insert -- create additional columns, read the data already in the table, update the table with results...I leave this to smarter people.

Comment: Hi donPablo, You are real smart and thanks for your help so far - actually I was saying my provided insert statement if you add a primary key column "TranscationId" which would help to you make record set bit more simplify and with less code - I'm not that good in SQL just a beginner that's why I was looking for some simple solution. Thanks you have a lovely weekend

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempRecords 
    (CODE VARCHAR(20), TRDATE DATE, TRBATCH INT, TRREF VARCHAR(20), TRXCODE INT, TRAMT decimal(8,2)
    );

    GO

    INSERT INTO #TempRecords
     VALUES ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 1753, 31.20),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8202, 3.12),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8104, 589.68),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, -31.20),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, -589.68),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, -3.12),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, 554.60),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, 32.18),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, 3.22),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
            ('ABMSC31', '2003-09-25', 8737, '0000060259', 1701, 1104.00)

    GO

declare @max_id int
;with cte as
(
select distinct t1.CODE, t1.TRDATE, t1.TRBATCH, t1.TRREF, t1.TRXCODE, t1.TRAMT, CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) TRAMT1, DENSE_RANK () OVER(ORDER BY CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))) as grp_id
from #TempRecords t1
join #TempRecords t2 on t1.TRAMT = CAST(IIF(t2.TRXCODE = 8202, t2.TRAMT, t2.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
or CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) = CAST(IIF(t2.TRXCODE = 8202, t2.TRAMT, t2.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
where CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
in (select CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
from #TempRecords t1 where t1.TRXCODE = 8202) or t1.TRAMT = CAST(IIF(t2.TRXCODE = 8202, t2.TRAMT, t2.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
)
select max(grp_id) grp_id into #t from cte
set @max_id = (select grp_id from #t)
drop table if exists #t
select t1.CODE, t1.TRDATE, t1.TRBATCH, t1.TRREF, t1.TRXCODE, t1.TRAMT, CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) TRAMT1, @max_id + row_number () OVER(ORDER BY CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))) as grp_id
from #TempRecords t1
where t1.TRXCODE <> 8202
and CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
not in (select CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) from #TempRecords t1 where t1.TRXCODE = 8202)
UNION
select distinct t1.CODE, t1.TRDATE, t1.TRBATCH, t1.TRREF, t1.TRXCODE, t1.TRAMT, CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) TRAMT1, DENSE_RANK () OVER(ORDER BY CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))) as grp_id
from #TempRecords t1
join #TempRecords t2 on t1.TRAMT = CAST(IIF(t2.TRXCODE = 8202, t2.TRAMT, t2.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
or CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) = CAST(IIF(t2.TRXCODE = 8202, t2.TRAMT, t2.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
where CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
in (select CAST(IIF(t1.TRXCODE = 8202, t1.TRAMT, t1.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
from #TempRecords t1 where t1.TRXCODE = 8202) or t1.TRAMT = CAST(IIF(t2.TRXCODE = 8202, t2.TRAMT, t2.TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
order by grp_id
```

Comment: Hi satishcse, Thanks for helping out your provided solution displays records as I want - Can you please produce such recrodset in a simple way as I have to merge this query in big query which already very lengthy and complex - Can you please use  #TempRecords  datasets without joining my query where I generated groupid - Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer and using #TempRecords only.

Comment: Thank for your help - Cheers